# Discord python bot: How to make embed message with member's highest role Colour?

Tags: python, discord.py

**I want to make a profile command with discord.py and I want the embed message has member's highest role colour.**

My code:

```
@client.command(passContent=True)
@commands.has_role("║Участники")
async def профиль(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    colour=member.Colour.default()
    профиль_сообщение=discord.Embed(
        title=f'Профиль {ctx.author.name}',
        colour=colour
        )
    await ctx.send(embed=профиль_сообщение)
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'Colour'
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.colour it's lower case `colour` not `Colour`. Also you don't want `.default()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This can be done by [`Member.top_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.top_role) and using [`Role.colour`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.colour) attribute**

Other things to notice:

- `passContent` is not a thing, its `pass_context` but that is not needed in rewrite

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("║Участники")
async def профиль(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    профиль_сообщение=discord.Embed(
        title=f'Профиль {ctx.author.name}',
        colour=member.top_role.colour
        )
    await ctx.send(embed=профиль_сообщение)
```